# use only one wireless card to connect to wifi network and share internet through wifi at same time

Tags: networking, wifi, connection-sharing

Is it possible to use only one wireless card to connect to other wifi network to access internet and share the internet to other devices via same wireless card at same time ?

**No! I didn't mean hotspot since it means only sharing internet of other network card's (example, eth0) via wifi**

I am doing two things at same time:

1. connect to other wifi using wireless card **wlan0**
2. share internet via same wireless card **wlan0**

Comment: you mean hotspot?

Comment: @Thushi no I didn't mean hotspot since it means only sharing internet via wifi

Comment: How is that **not** a hotspot?

Comment: @Celada HotSpot just share other network card's (example, eth0) internet

Comment: I don't think it matters where the upstream Internet connection is coming from, it's still a hotspot. Wikipedia says: "A hotspot is a site that offers Internet access over a wireless local area network (WLAN) through the use of a router connected to a link to an Internet service provider. Hotspots typically use Wi-Fi technology."

Comment: @Celada have you ever tried what I mean to say ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it, hence my answer is unable to give details (sorry), but there are some commercial product that do something similar. They are sold as "repeaters".

Comment: this helped me, found it on askubuntu

http://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to share internet through same wireless card through which you are connect to some WIFI.

You have to check whether your wireless card supports this feature or not. Following links will help you to do so:

1. [Connectify for Linux with Single wireless interface](http://linuxalfi.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/connectify-for-linux-with-single-wireless-interface/)
2. [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that some, but not all wifi chipsets will allow 2 subinterfaces, one of them in master mode and one of them in client mode.

The difficulty is that there is only one radio. The client subinterface needs to search for the SSID it wants to join and set the radio to the same channel as the access point it associates to. Master subinterfaces, on the other hand, are normally set to a fixed channel. You may have difficulty getting things configured so that the two subinterfaces don't step on each other's channel settings. The usual tools for configuring wifi interfaces probably won't help you with that task. Hardcoding the channel number all around seems the best option.

One way or the other, you'll be stuck with both subinterfaces on the same channel, which means you only have half the bandwidth available, because the same traffic has to go in and back out on the same radio frequencies.

Comment: Your question asks about using the same wifi card for both networks, hence that's what my answer is talking about, and hence the limitation of only one radio. If you have multiple wifi cards that it's a totally different question and it's much easier.

Comment: your answer is still vague. atleast mention any product or technical description of such card

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know vendors or models of cards that will work. Perhaps someone else with concrete experience will provide a better answer.

Comment: then from where you came to know ? haha

Comment: From working with commercially available "repeaters" and half-remembered perusals through madwifi source code.

Comment: is this not possible by any way on computers ? one guy was claiming that he did it on his windows computer using connectify and wanted to know a method on ubuntu

Comment: PLEASE! I already told you I don't have specifics on which chipsets support it and which don't. You are welcom to wait for someone to come along with a more detailed answer. I merely thought that sharing my knowledge of the inherent challenges involved might be useful to you. If you'd rather not hear it then let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer, Celada. I'm speechless seeing how few credit you get trying to help some people on SE.